# Selecting every last element of tr series

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Firstly, I have no control over the markup, I am merely styling this.

I have a table with a series of rows, some rows have a class in consecutive order. I've been able to select the first element of the series but can't manage to select the last.

Any ideas?

Here is an example:

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the css I have for selecting the first element of each child series is:

```
table tr.parent + tr.child
```

I cannot use jQuery!!!! this has to be pure CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :last-child selector.  Example:

```
table tr:last-child
```

This will select every tr which is the last element in its parent; in this case, the last `tr` in the table.  More about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child

The `+` is the adjacent child selector, and in your example will select any `tr.parent` which has `tr.parent` as a sibling immediately before it.  More about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS 3 Selectors, if your browser supports them (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Per the [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/), you can used something like:

```
tr.parent:last-of-type
```

Comment: i want to select each child before a new parent begins, not the last of all .child's